# How to make a for loop work in a property inside of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is an app that, when clicking add recipe button, brings up a pop up. This lets you put a recipe name and recipe ingredients into the input boxes. Pressing the add recipe button in that popup box should render the recipe names that were stored in localStorage.

Right now my Recipe list uses an empty array called list, and uses a for loop to add the localStorage items to the list array. Right now though it only works on page load, not when clicking the add recipe button. It's because it isn't able to update the array since I currently have it outside the component, but putting it in made it not load any list items.

component in question:

```
var React = require("react");

var Recipe = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        list: ""
      };  
    },

    updateList: function() {
      var list = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length - 1; i++)  {      
         var key = window.localStorage.key(i);
         list.push(window.localStorage.getItem(key));         
      }

      this.setState({
        list: list
      });      
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.updateList();  
    },


    render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="full-recipe">
            {this.state.list.map(function(item) {
              return (
                <div className="recipe">
                  <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                </div>            
              );
            })}
            <button onClick={function() { this.updateList()}}>refresh the list</button>
          </div> 
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Recipe;
```

full code: https://github.com/jeffm64/recipe-box/blob/master/src/components/recipe.js

Comment: Your question is rather vague. I suggest you take a look at [this SO help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I reworded it to try and have it make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

i checked your code, you can change addRecipe function in popupbox.js to this:

```
addRecipe: function() {
  var recipeName = document.querySelector(".recipe-name").value;
  var counter = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("counter"));
  window.localStorage.setItem("counter", counter++);
  var recipes = window.localStorage.getItem("recipes");
  if (!recipes)
    recipes = [];
  else
    recipes = JSON.parse(recipes);
  recipes.push({name: recipeName});
  window.localStorage.setItem("recipes", JSON.stringify(recipes));
  this.updateList();
},
```

then updateList:

```
updateList: function() {
  var list = window.localStorage.getItem('recipes');
  if (list)
    list = JSON.parse(list);
  else
    list = [{}];        

  this.setState({
    list: list
  });      
},
```

and don't forget about key in render function

```
{this.state.list.map(function(item, idx) {
  return (
    <div className="recipe" key={idx}>
      <h2>{item.name}</h2>
    </div>            
  );
})}
```

Comment: I tried out this code and I get a console error of "this.state.list.map is not a function". Do have code link with all of that code inserted? Perhaps I didn't insert everything corrrectly.

Comment: in getInitialState try change list:"" to list: []

Answer (score 0):

It's better to keep all localStorage access in one place, in a parent component, and propagate it down using props.

A child component (like your 'pop up') can receive a callback function via props to propagate something back upwards.

This official article explains this beautifully:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

And here is a very  simple example of this happening:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbMrdL?editors=1010

```
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {recipes:[]}
    this.loadRecipes = this.loadRecipes.bind(this)
    this.addRecipe = this.addRecipe.bind(this)
    this.deleteAllRecipes = this.deleteAllRecipes.bind(this)
  }

  loadRecipes(){
    const storedRecepes = window.localStorage.getItem('recipes')
    const recipes = storedRecepes?JSON.parse(storedRecepes):[]
    this.setState({recipes:recipes}) 
  }
  addRecipe(recipe){
    const recipes = [...this.state.recipes, recipe]
    this.setState({recipes:recipes})
    window.localStorage.setItem('recipes',JSON.stringify(recipes))
  }
  deleteAllRecipes(recipe){
    this.setState({recipes:[]})
    window.localStorage.setItem('recipes',JSON.stringify([]))
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.loadRecipes()
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <RecipesList recipes={this.state.recipes} />
        <RecipeAdd onRecepeAdded={this.addRecipe} />
        <RecipeDeleteAll onRecepesDeleted={this.deleteAllRecipes} />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class RecipesList extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Recipes</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.props.recipes.map((recipe, idx)=>
            <li key={idx}>{recipe.name}</li>
           )}
         </ul>
      </div>)
  }
}

class RecipeAdd extends React.Component{

  add(){
    const name = window.prompt("recepe name:")
    this.props.onRecepeAdded({name:name})
  }

  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Add</button>
  }
}

class RecipeDeleteAll extends React.Component{

  deleteAll(){
    if(confirm('Delete all?')){
      this.props.onRecepesDeleted()
    }
  }

  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.deleteAll.bind(this)}>Delete All</button>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: That link was pretty helpful in terms of how to build an app so thank you for that! As for your code it's hard for me to really understand that as I haven't learned ES6. I didn't want to try to learn a framework and new syntax at the same time.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoqzXr?editors=1010

let me know if I forgot any ES6 behind

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look over it and see if I can't try to better build the app.